# How can I run code on a BrowserView before loadUrl in Electron?

Tags: electron

I'm trying to set the local storage and cookies of a website before it loads, under the hood.
I am able to do it from the preload but it starts running only when you call loadUrl, which means it could result in a race condition.
Same goes with executeJavascript.

Is there a way to have code execution in the BrowserView context, but guarantee it runs before the website loads?
Delaying/blocking the loadUrl could work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You actually already have the solution

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/glossary#preload-script

> Preload scripts contain code that executes in a renderer process before its web contents begin loading. These scripts run within the renderer context, but are granted more privileges by having access to Node.js APIs.

Your code will be ran ***before*** it begins loading, not at the same time